# Angular 5, two components on same page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I want to see if there is anyway I can see another component to be rendered on the same page as I am in. I have:

```
<button mat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/tripspath', trip.tripId]" style="cursor: pointer">View Route</button>
```

Which navigates to tripspath component and it works fine while the tripspath get the tripId as:

```
var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

But the problem is I dont want it to navigate to another page. I want it to stay on the same page and just show the box (of route) below the current content.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a way to display nested routes.
check the article below , it would help you.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/

Answer (score 1):

Dont user a router link.  Embed the component with an *ngIf attribute toggled by your button that starts off being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Then you must add the element to show behind the button and use `*ngIf` to show or hide the component

```
<button mat-button color="primary" (click)="showComponent()" style="cursor: pointer">View Route</button>
<trip-component *ngIf="trip.tripId==25"></trip-component>
```

in component.ts

```
showComponent(){
   trip.tripId=25;
}
```

`<trip-component>` could be a custom component or just a simple div element with the code to show inside.

Comment: I was thinking about ngIf but the point is I want it to be rendered once the button is clicked. the button is passing the tripId to the router.

Comment: That's why I put  the click event there you can send the id  as parameter   and you will show what ever you want using the id, an example could be `*ngIf = "trip.tripId > 0"` then you show the component

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to navigate it to another page you should use child route.
click on the link to see working example of your scenario.[child route example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1tu2ev)